# How does gradle parses a dependency in string notation

Tags: java, gradle, dependency-management, ivy

As per the documentation http://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.dsl.DependencyHandler.html

A string dependency notation looks like "group:name:version:classifier@extension"
How do we specify the type (http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/terminology.html#type) here?

Comment: To clarify, I cannot use gradle's map notation here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to specify a classifier in a gradle dependency's dependency?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13188438/how-to-specify-a-classifier-in-a-gradle-dependencys-dependency)

Answer (score 0):

You can declare like below:

```
artifacts {
  archives file: '', name: '', type: 'jar'
}
```

and for more information [here](http://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.Project.html#org.gradle.api.Project:artifacts%28groovy.lang.Closure%29).

Comment: Thanks GAgarwal, but I'm limited here and cannot use the Map notation

Comment: Please check the below link not to use map notation:http://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.query.ArtifactResolutionQuery.html